# Making your Android app selectable to handle making a call

Tags: android

I've had got allot of help from stackoverflow with programming problems over the years just off google. I have finally run into an issue that i cant solve despite exhaustive searching and looking at different resources on the net. So i am finally making my first post here..

Here's my issue

I'm writing an android dialer app that behaves like a phone app. I need it so that when the user goes to make a call by tapping a contacts phone number, the operating system asks the user if they want to use my app or the default android phone app to carry out the call.

There is a couple of approaches to this i have found that work to different degrees.

Putting this into the manifest along with requesting relevant permissions.

`<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
</intent-filter>`

This worked but not well enough as it failed to work on api 19 or higher. At the time of writing we are upto api 23 (marshmallow). Also using CALL_PRIVILEGED is not recommended.

The second way is using a NEW_OUTGOING_CALL intent receiver, which involves creating a class that extents off BroadcastReceiver, to listen for when the phone attempts to start a call.

```
 <receiver android:name=".OutgoingCallReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

[tutorial here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2013/05/handling-phone-call-requests-right-way.html)

This way worked but to well in the sense that it doesn't even ask the user what app they want to call using and goes straight to my app. Even testing on the latest marshmallow with the right permissions it happily let me take over the phone and effectively force the user to use my app for making calls!

Can anyone help or have run into this issue before?

Comment: Its been stated that CALL_PRIVILEGED is not intended for third party apps, perhaps this is being blocked as of api 19? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CALL_PRIVILEGED

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CALL_PRIVILEGED

Comment: It appears that CALL_PRIVILEGED is restricted and discouraged from use in third party apps. If security is the concern surely the NEW_OUTGOING_CALL is more of a worry as you can silently listen and intercept and even block out going calls without asking the user anything. Either way i cant get CALL_PRIVILEGED working on android 4 onwards. I followed the way it was done in skypes manifest, there really isn't much to it. Has anyone ever got this working on the newer androids 4 and above?! Does skype even work?! Does skype perhaps have some kind of signed permissions giving them more access?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the manifest of Skype or other apps that add this functionality. A quick look at Skype got me this;

```
<intent-filter        
    icon="@drawable/skype_blue"
    priority="0">
    <action name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <action name="android.intent.action.CALL"/>
        <action name="android.intent.action.DIAL"/>
        <action name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED"/>
        <category name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data scheme="tel"/>
</intent-filter>
```

I just looked at TrueCaller (and it seems to work better in OS 6 (but not always) and here is the manifest details that might interest you.

```
<uses-permission name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED"/>

<activity theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" name="com.truecaller.ui.DialerIntentProxy" taskAffinity="com.truecaller.dialer" launchMode="singleInstance" noHistory="true">
   <intent-filter>
      <action name="com.truecaller.OPEN_DIALER" />
      <category name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter>
   <intent-filter>
      <action name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
      <category name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter>
   <intent-filter>
      <action name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
      <category name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data scheme="voicemail" />
   </intent-filter>
   <intent-filter>
      <action name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
      <category name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/phone" />
      <data mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/person" />
   </intent-filter>
   <intent-filter>
      <action name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <action name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
      <category name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data scheme="tel" />
   </intent-filter>
   <intent-filter>
      <action name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
      <category name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
   </intent-filter>
   <intent-filter>
      <action name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/calls" />
   </intent-filter>
   <intent-filter>
      <action name="com.android.phone.action.RECENT_CALLS" />
      <category name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
   <intent-filter>
      <action name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <data mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/calls" />
   </intent-filter>
   <intent-filter>
      <action name="com.sec.android.app.dialertab.calllog.DetailViewActivity" />
      <category name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter>
   <intent-filter>
      <action name="com.sec.android.app.dialertab.calllog.LogsListActivity" />
      <category name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter>
   <intent-filter>
      <action name="android.intent.action.SEARCH_LONG_PRESS" />
      <category name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Remember, I am just using this for educational purposes. Re-using the code might have copyright issues.

Comment: I can only seem to find older versions without the call intent filter. Where about's did you find the Skype manifest?

Comment: I just used the app called "App Detective" on the Skype installed on my device, and read the manifest.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately despite adding the extra intent actions it made no difference and like before will only work on older versions before api 19.

Comment: Looking at TrueCaller we can see it relies on the CALL_PRIVILEGED permission. BUT when i attempt to put this in my manifest android studio gives me a "Permission is only granted to system apps"n error. So it looks like as of api 19 it is being blocked to third party apps.

Comment: Why something as simple as letting the user choose your app when making a call is a privileged system function yet i can write something that can intercept and block, manipulate an out going call in any way i like without the user even knowing!?

Comment: You are right TrueCaller does work on api 23. I did a quick test and found that the new run-time permission granting introduced in marshmallow some how didn't enforce or throw an exception with the "system app" only rule on CALL_PRIVILEGED. So my app now works with api 23! I dont understand but at least something works!

Comment: I will write up a solution on how to get it working on api 23 for anyone else who runs into this. As for api=>19 and <23 this is still not solved

Comment: Try TrueCaller on 22

Comment: Tried TrueCaller on 16 19 and 22. None worked. api 19 and 22 were virtual devices, 16 was on an old galaxy. This seems to be a real hit and miss. Skype shows up on 16 but no TrueCaller. Ill put up my best effort solution later to help others stuck on this which at least does work on the latest android marshmallow as of writing.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this on api 23 android marshmallow and future android versions pending tests.

Add this in the manifest inside the default launcher `<activity>` tags.

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:scheme="tel"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

Gain CALL_PRIVILEGED access by adding this into your code, such as when your activity first launches. This checks if the permission is granted and if it isn't it will ask the user for access.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
        Manifest.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED {
        if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
        Manifest.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED},
            PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PRIVILEGED);
        }
    }
}
```

Add this constant somewhere, such as the top of the activity file.

`public static int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PRIVILEGED = 1;`

This still seems to work on older android versions but not api 19 (Kitcat) onwards. I'm guessing this may be because i was unable to put a request for CALL_PRIVILEGED in the manifest, as android studio throws an error sayings its for system apps only and won't compile.